# How to use correctly isalnum function in C?

Tags: c, fifo, mkfifo

I tried to check if a character of a string is alnum and then if the string contains only alnum characters to print the string. When I run the program nothing happens. I have another program with whom I read from the input the text I want and I send it with FIFO. If i don;t include in the program the "check" function it works, after that it doesn't.

```
void    put_alphanum(char *str)
{
while (*str)
{
    if (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9')
        write(1, str, 1);
    else if (*str >= 'A' && *str <= 'Z')
        write(1, str, 1);
    else if (*str >= 'a' && *str <= 'z')
        write(1, str, 1);
    str++;
}
write(1,"\n",1);
}
```

This is the function I used to print the string. If I don't put it together with the check function the program works.

```
int check(char *str)
{

while(*str)
{
if(isalnum(*str)==0)
return 0;

str++;
}

return 1;

}
```

This is the function I use to check if a string contains just alnum characters. But if I don;t include this function in my program, the program works. I think here is the problem. And the main function()

```
int     main()
{
int fd;
int len;
char buf[BUFF_SIZE + 1];

mkfifo(FIFO_LOC, 0666);
fd = open(FIFO_LOC, O_RDONLY);
while(1)
{
    while((len = read(fd, buf, BUFF_SIZE)))
    {
        buf[len] = '\0';
        if(check(buf)==1)
             put_alphanum(buf);

    }
}
return (0);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... so you have a function that checks to see if a string contains only alphanumeric characters, then you have a function that prints only the alphanumeric characters of that string? Does the input string contain a `\n`?

Comment: in the main before I check I put to the string a '\0' at the end

Comment: Also, this sort of thing is not portable: `if (*str >= 'A' && *str <= 'Z')`. C makes few restrictions on character set encoding. Some real-world encodings, EBCDIC for example, do not encode letters in a contiguous sequence, causing this method to fail. Not that this is your problem, though.

Comment: while (1)
 {
  while ((len = read(0, buf, BUFF_SIZE)))
  {
  
   buf[len] = '\0';
   write(fd, buf, len);
  }
 }   This is the way I read from input characters

Comment: I think that @DavidBowling got the point: your buffer contains non alfanum chars, most probably a  `\n` (`0x0a`) or space (`0x020`)

Comment: You read `BUFF_SIZE` characters, but is the string that you read actually of length `BUFF_SIZE`? What does the input look like?

Comment: BTW you should post the input data (file content)

Comment: @DavidBowling That doesn't matter. OP is terminating the string with read returned length.

Comment: It works now, that was the problem with \n . Thank you very much!

Comment: @DavidBowling You should post the answer then ;)

Comment: @LPs-- I would, but it still feels like any answer I wrote would be a guess since the nature of the input is still unknown. If OP is reading `BUFF_SIZE` characters, and input line lengths vary, then the resulting strings may be garbled if `\n` is simply replaced with `\0`. I may be missing something; feel free to post an answer if you have more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Input text contains '\n' and that means that the string is not an alphanumeric string. When I read I push the enter button and that means one more character in the string.